# Creating a scatter plot from a dataframe with dates on x-axis creates overlap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

So I have a dataframe that consists of several variables, such as the amount of comments from an instagram page and the upload date of each post. For this, I used the package Instascrape
Now I want to make a scatter plot from these two variables, with the date on the x-axis and amount of comments on the y-axis using the following command:

```
plt.scatter(posts_df["upload_date"], posts_df["likes"])
plt.show()
```

Now I face the following problem, I get the scatter plot but the dates are overlapping. I believe that this is due to the fact that it shows every date on the x-axis, if they are close to each other the dates are overlapping.

I tried to convert it using:

```
plt.scatter(posts_df["upload_date"], posts_df["comments"])
plt.show()
```

But that did not change anything. The dates look like this: upload_date
0   2020-12-26 01:23:57

how can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by using simply the command:

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```